# Integrating QML and C++ for login purposes

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to create a simple login app, which will authenticate via Google Firebase. So far, I have the authentication code working fine.
Header file:

```
#ifndef AUTHHANDLER_H
#define AUTHHANDLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QJsonDocument>

class AuthHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit AuthHandler(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~AuthHandler();
    void setAPIKey(const QString & apiKey);
    void signUserUp(const QString & emailAddress, const QString & password);
    void signUserIn(const QString & emailAddress, const QString & password);

public slots:
    void networkReplyReadyRead();

    void performAuthenticatedDatabaseCall();

signals:
    void userSignedIn();

private:
   void performPOST( const QString & url, const QJsonDocument & payload);
   void parseResponse( const QByteArray & response);
   QString m_apiKey;
   QNetworkAccessManager * m_networkAccessManager;
   QNetworkReply * m_networkReply;
   QString m_idToken;


};

#endif // AUTHHANDLER_H
```

Authentication .cpp file

```
#include "authhandler.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVariantMap>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QJsonObject>

AuthHandler::AuthHandler(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
    , m_apiKey( QString() )
{
    m_networkAccessManager = new QNetworkAccessManager( this );
    connect( this, &AuthHandler::userSignedIn, this, &AuthHandler::performAuthenticatedDatabaseCall );
}

AuthHandler::~AuthHandler()
{
   m_networkAccessManager->deleteLater();
}

void AuthHandler::setAPIKey(const QString &apiKey)
{
    m_apiKey = apiKey;
}

void AuthHandler::signUserUp(const QString &emailAddress, const QString &password)
{
    QString signUpEndpoint = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=" + m_apiKey;

    QVariantMap variantPayload;
    variantPayload["email"] = emailAddress;
    variantPayload["password"] = password;
    variantPayload["returnSecureToken"] = true;

    QJsonDocument jsonPayload = QJsonDocument::fromVariant( variantPayload );
    performPOST( signUpEndpoint, jsonPayload);

}

void AuthHandler::signUserIn(const QString &emailAddress, const QString &password)
{
    QString signInEndpoint = "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=" + m_apiKey;

    QVariantMap variantPayload;
    variantPayload["email"] = emailAddress;
    variantPayload["password"] = password;
    variantPayload["returnSecureToken"] = true;

    QJsonDocument jsonPayload = QJsonDocument::fromVariant( variantPayload );
    performPOST( signInEndpoint, jsonPayload);

}
```

main.cpp file

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "authhandler.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

   // AuthHandler authHandler;
    //authHandler.setAPIKey("AIzaSyB-nAN8OlgxHzXC5gpISkodjEZJ7IdSpgI");
   // authHandler.signUserIn("user2@user.com", "password123!");



    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    AuthHandler authHandler;
    authHandler.setAPIKey("AIzaSyB-nAN8OlgxHzXC5gpISkodjEZJ7IdSpgI");
    authHandler.signUserIn("user3@user.com", "password123!");



    return app.exec();
}
```

As you can see, I'm currently hardcoding the values used in the SignUserIn function. These values are then updated in Firebase, and this is working. My question is, how do I make it so that the hard-coded values are input by an user in a qml file? I created a qml file with the required layout, but I'm having trouble setting it up so that the .cpp file function executes when a button is clicked in qml.

Comment: There are tons of [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) on the internet about this. Just search for `C++ QML` in Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make the method signUserIn a slot in the AuthHandler class

   ```
   public slots: 
       void signUserIn(const QString & emailAddress, const QString & password);
   ```
2. Register your AuthHandler to the QML engine in main.cpp

   ```
   qmlRegisterSingletonInstance("AuthHandler", 1, 0, "AuthHandler", &authHandler);
   ```
3. Import the AuthHandler in QML

   ```
   import AuthHandler
   ```
4. Send the user credentials from QML to your handler

   ```
        TextEdit {
            id: user
            text: "user"
        }

        TextEdit {
            id: password
            text: "password"
        }

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Login");
            onClicked: {
                console.log("login: " + user.text + " password: " + password.text);
                AuthHandler.signUserIn(user.text, password.text);
            }
        }
   ```

Comment: The qmlRegisteringSingletonInstance line returns an error of undeclared identifier. Do i need to initialize a static member or something for it to work? I made sure the identifier reflected exactly the authhandler.cpp file name

Comment: change it to qmlRegisterSingletonInstance("AuthHandler", 1, 0, "AuthHandler", &authHandler); or create a scoped pointer for your AuthHandler instance

Comment: QScopedPointer<AuthHandler> authHandler(new AuthHandler); qmlRegisterSingletonInstance("AuthHandler", 1, 0, "AuthHandler", authHandler.get());

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. My current main.cpp code:     
AuthHandler authHandler;
    authHandler.setAPIKey("AIzaSyB-nAN8OlgxHzXC5gpISkodjEZJ7IdSpgI");
    //authHandler.signUserIn("user3@user.com", "password123!");
    qmlRegisterSingletonInstance("AuthHandler", 1, 0, "AuthHandler", &authHandler);

Comment: My qml file is unchanged. Upon running the application i get the error, module 'AuthHandler' is not installed.

Comment: Do you use CMAKE as build system?  If yes, is there a line set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON) in your CMakeLists.txt? Try to delete your build folder an rebuild your project. Sometimes caching leads to some problems.

Comment: I found the fix, one of my directory path for the module was wrong. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Cool! Your welcome. Don't forget to mark this question as solved then!